Create GitHub PAT that can download npm packages from another repository
I need a PAT for a GitHub Actions workflow that I can use in my .npmrc to download packages from another private repository in our organization.
If I use the gh CLI and and take the token from gh auth token that has the correct scope read:packages, and put that in my secret for the workflow to use, it works.
But I can't find how to add the read:packages scope to a PAT created for our org level service account.
How do I create a PAT that has the appropriate scope/permissions?
